# check network connectivity in the mobile device and handle

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to check the device online before calling the API in the below method

```
1. If connectivity call api.
2. If no connectivity just show alert.
```

can some one help here

```
getArea() {

this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: "loading..."
});
this.loading.present();
this.userID = "jmzw";
return this.http
    .post(OMWConstants._postsURL + "Areas", 'userID="' + this.userID + '"', {
        headers: this.getPostAPIHeader()
    }
).toPromise().then(data => {
    this.saveArea(data);
    this.loading.dismiss();
    return data;
}).catch(error => {
    this.loading.dismiss();
    this.handleError(error);
});
}
```

Comment: Acc to me, best thing is to check at application level if device is online and accordingly there itself you can show generic error. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you can check it at application level with Ionic Native / Network for instance but it cannot tell you whether the device has internet access. So I would do it in the way you are already doing it: call http.post() and if it returns with a particular error then you know that the server / other node is not available.